Twitter OAUTH error: Could not authenticate you
Estoy hacendo la autentificacion para request una "token request" en twiiter (X), pero no despues de investigar y leer mucho, creo que mi problema esta en que estoy haciendo mal la "oauth_signature".
Siempre me da el error de Could not authenticate you, les pongo aqui mi codigo en PHP:
cat test.php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$urlTokenRequest= 'https://api.x.com/oauth/request_token';
$appKey= '__my_consumer_key__'; // key de la app
$appSecret= '__my_consumer_secret__'; // secret de la app
$tokenSecret= NULL; // esta no la usamos, porque aun no obtenemos la token
$firmaTwitter=0; // aqui guardaremos la firma
$fecha= time(); // la "huella" sera el tiempo
$nonce= md5($fecha); // el tiempo en md5
$oauthArr= array(
    "oauth_consumer_key"=>$appKey,
    "oauth_signature_method"=>"HMAC-SHA1", 
    "oauth_timestamp"=>$fecha, 
    "oauth_nonce"=>$nonce,
    "oauth_version"=>"1.0"
);

// este sera el "string" que se firmara y obtendremos el hash
$baseString= (
    "GET". // metodo
    '&'. rawurlencode($urlTokenRequest). // url con path
    '&'. rawurlencode(http_build_query($oauthArr, '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986)) // argumentos
);
$keys= rawurlencode($appSecret). '&'. ($tokenSecret ? rawurlencode($tokenSecret):"");
$firmaTwitter= base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $baseString, $keys, true));

// agregando firma
$oauthArr["oauth_signature"]= $firmaTwitter;

$s= curl_init();
$urlService= $urlTokenRequest;
$urlService .= '?'.http_build_query($oauthArr, '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);

curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_URL, $urlService );
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8") );
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1 );
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($s, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
$resp= curl_exec($s);
$rq= curl_getinfo($s);

echo "\n>>> Informacion General\nApp Key: ". $appKey;
echo "\nApp Secret: ". $appSecret;
echo "\nBaseString: ". $baseString;
echo "\nKey: ". $keys;
echo "\nFirma: ". $firmaTwitter;
echo "\nURL a Consumir: ". $urlService;
echo "\nArreglo OAuth:\n";
print_r($oauthArr);
echo "\n\n>>> Resquest\n";
print_r($rq["request_header"]);

echo "\n\n>>> Response\n";
print_r($resp);

?>

Basicamente al ejecutarlo deberia arrojarme el "token" y "token_secret", ya con esos se supone que cuando mande un twit o mire el estatus, pues seria igual el proceso de la forma pero adicionalmente agregaremos el "token_secret" al $keys antes de firmar, y en el "oauthArray" deberiamos agregar el status del nuevo twit o algo...
Pero bueno, la baseprincipal que es el Request Token, no esta funcionando :( y sin eso, sigo sin poder hacer algo..
